# SQL Join 2 tables with date difference

Tags: sql, database

I have 2 tables, one of which is orders and the other one is receipts. The problem I am facing is that they don't have UID, the only thing they can be joined with is the date. Problem with that is, the date is the same, but the time difference between them is approx 30 seconds. My question is, is there any way I can join these 2 tables?

So, the 1st table is in the following format

```
|   date        | order | price | 
|1/1/13 06:05:32|  tea  |   3   |
|1/2/13 07:04:24| coffee|   2   |
|4/3/13 13:31:23|  tea  |   3   |
```

And the second table has this format

```
|   date        | order | quantity | 
|1/1/13 06:05:42|  tea  |   3      |
|1/2/13 07:04:54| coffee|   2      |
|4/3/13 13:31:56|  tea  |   3      |
```

My desired output is

```
|   date        | order | quantity |  price | 
|1/1/13 06:05:42|  tea  |   3      |    3   |
|1/2/13 07:04:54| coffee|   2      |    2   |
|4/3/13 13:31:56|  tea  |   3      |    3   |
```

Basically, my goal here is to combine these 2 tables so i can see the differences between them, but I don't have an idea how to join them without unique ID's, please help guys

Comment: What are the rules for combining them?

Comment: cast datetime to date and join by date

Comment: I only in theory need the date and the order in the final table. My goal is to see the differences between them,to find out which ones dont match, so i guess i dont have any rules, my goal is to combine them however i can

Comment: I would join by date, but the differ from 5 to 45 seconds

Comment: If you can make sure that per day there will only one transaction per product, you can join using the date part only. But still there will be issue if that 5 to 45 sec diff make entry in 2 different days :(

Comment: Yeah, i was thinking about that, the only problem is that i have multiple products per day, so the final table is not valid :/

Comment: Tag with the database you are using.

Comment: If you can make sure order of data in both table will be always same, I mean row number X is in table1 always belongs to row number X in table2, you can then use row_number and JOIN both table using ROW_NUMBER. This could be an option.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one solution (tried on SQLite3 but it's similar for other DBMS if you replace with the corresponding date function):

```
create table orders([date],[order],price);
insert into orders values
('2013-01-01 06:05:32', 'tea',  3),
('2013-01-02 07:04:24','coffee',2),
('2013-04-03 13:31:23', 'tea',  3);

create table receipts([date],[order],quantity);
insert into receipts values
('2013-01-01 06:05:42', 'tea',  3),
('2013-01-02 07:04:54','coffee',2),
('2013-04-03 13:31:56', 'tea',  3);

-- My desired output is
--
-- |   date        | order | quantity |  price |
-- |1/1/13 06:05:42|  tea  |   3      |    3   |
-- |1/2/13 07:04:54| coffee|   2      |    2   |
-- |4/3/13 13:31:56|  tea  |   3      |    3   |

select r.[date],[order],quantity,price
  from orders o join receipts r using([order])
  where r.date > o.date
    and r.date < datetime(o.date,'+40 seconds')
```

or even:

```
select r.[date],[order],quantity,price
  from orders o join receipts r using([order])
  where r.date between o.date and datetime(o.date,'+40 seconds')
```

I used 40 seconds (you say approximately 30 seconds but your example output grabs the 33 second difference).  Adjust as needed.  I also assume (based on your example) that orders always come before receipts.

Answer (score 1):

You could enumerate by the date value and join on that:

```
select t2.*, t1.*
from (select t1.*, row_number() over (partition by product order by date) as seqnum
      from t1
     ) t1 join
     (select t2.*, row_number() over (partition by product order by date) as seqnum
      from t2
     ) t2 
     on t1.product = t2.product and
        t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum;
```

You can also join on the time difference:

```
select t2.*, t1.*
from t2 join
     t1
     on t2.product = t1.product and
        t2.date >= dateadd(second, -30, t1.date) and
        t2.date < dateadd(second, 30, t1.date);
```

Or use `apply` to get the nearest time up to the time in `t2`:

```
select t2.*, t1.*
from t2 outer appy
     (select top (1) t1.*
      from t1
      where t1.product = t2.product and
            t1.date <= t2.date and
            t1.date > dateadd(second, -60, t2.date)  -- just to keep within a range
      order by t1.date desc
     ) t1;
```

Comment: There isnt the same number of products in the order table and in the receipt table, thats the problem.I have to find every missmatch

Answer (score 0):

In SQL server you can do something like this:

```
select *
from ( select *, convert(date, getdate()) as d1 from t1) as t1,
( select *, convert(date, getdate()) as d2 from t2) as t2
where t1.d1 = t2.d2
and t1.order = t2.order
```

The point here is to convert date and time to only date and join the two tables.

Comment: Thanks for the response, the problem is they dont have matching dates, they differ 30 seconds on average

Comment: I removed time from my query so instead of 1/1/13 06:05:42 you will have 1/1/13 only so dates will match :)

Comment: Problem is that i have multiple orders per day, so the output wont be the desired one

Comment: why not? You won't lose data with join so for example the first row of the first table will match with the first row of the second and give the desired output. Even if you have another order on the 1/1/13 it will be included I'll edit my query to match the product type

Comment: just edited now order match per day and type without losing any order and without any mismatch

Comment: The database has a lot of orders per day, so there will be complications again, it is close to the solution, but it isnt quite right if u know what i mean

Comment: I can't understand why numbers of orders is a problem, with the query I provided you will have all orders... do you mean that you want avoid duplicates of the order for the same type and sum quantities?

Comment: I want to say that i have to have full time stamp in the desired table. Will the query u provided keep the full timestamp and just join by date+order?

Comment: yes of course, there are even more columns in the result query but you can work on the upper select statement and select only what you want. In the final result you will have datetime and date but you can select datetime at the end and cutoff unwanted columns :)

Comment: I will give it a try and report back in! Thank you for ur help!

Answer (score 0):

If you can make sure order of data in both table will be always same, I mean row number X is in table1 always belongs to row number X in table2, you can then use row_number and JOIN both table using ROW_NUMBER. This could be an option.

```
SELECT A.Date, A.Order, A.Price, B.quantity
FROM 
(
    SELECT  Date, Order, Price,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN
    FROM Table1
)A
INNER JOIN 
(
        SELECT  Date, Order, quantity,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN
)B ON A.RN = B.RN
```

Comment: unfortunately it isnt, im doing this exactly because the data in both tables isnt the same as it should be

Comment: Then bad luck :( @FilipStankovic